# Fast algorithm for calculating union of 'local convex hulls'

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry

I have a set of 2D points from which I want to generate a polygon (or collection of polygons) outlining the 'shape' of those points, *using the following concept*:

For each point in the set, calculate the convex hull of all points within radius R of that point. After doing this for each point, take the union of these convex hulls to produce the final shape.

A brute force approach of actually constructing all these convex hulls is something like O(N^2 + R^2 log R). Is there a known, more efficient algorithm to produce the same result? Or perhaps a different way of expressing the problem?

Note: I am aware of alpha shapes, they are different; I am looking for an algorithm to perform what is described above.

---

The following solution does not work - disproved experimentally in MATLAB.

<strike>Update: I have a proposed solution.</strike>

Proposition: take the Delaunay Triangulation of the set of points, remove all triangles having circumradius greater than R. Then take the union of the remaining triangles.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Is it a non-convex hull that represents the shape of the point-cloud better than a convex one?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. A bit like alpha shapes: http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.4/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_2/Chapter_main.html. Except that my method produces visually nicer results (IMO) for the data I am working with.

Answer (score 1):

A [sweep line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) can improve searching for the R-neighbors. Alternatively, you can consider only pairs of points that are in  neighboring squares of square grid of width R. Both of these ideas can get rid of the N^2 - of course only if the points are relatively sparse.

I believe that a clever combination of sweeping and convex hull finding cat get rid of the N^2 even if the points are not sparse (as in Olexiy's example), but cannot come up with a concrete algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm now trying to nut out a solution using a sweep line approach. Will be sure to post back if I come up with a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using rotating calipers. My prof wrote [some stuff](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~binay/406/ConvexHull.2.pdf) on this, it starts on page 19.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting info, but I'm not sure how it can be used to solve the problem. I see how rotating calipers are used to find tangents to merge subset convex hulls into a single convex hull, but that is different from the union of convex hulls - the result can be concave or contain holes for instance. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh... I think I misunderstood what you meant by the "union". I assumed you wanted the to merge them into a single convex hull. In that case, I'm not really sure if there are any benefits to be had using hulls vs non-convex polygons. I suggest you look at existing algorithms and see if there are any tweaks you can make to take advantage of the properties of a convex polygon.

Comment: Ok cool, yes I might not be using the 'right' terminology either. Anyway, I've added a proposed solution to my question above - if you have any thoughts on it, let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I misunderstood the problem.

I don't see how do you get N^2 time for brute-forcing all convex hulls in the worst case (**1**). What if almost any 2 points are closer than R - in this case you need at least N^2*logN to just construct the convex hulls, leave alone computing their union.

Also, where does R^2*logR in your estimation comes from?

**1** The worst case (as I see it) for a huge N - take a circle of radius R / 2 and randomly place points on its border and just outside it.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't very clear with that. O(N^2 + R^2 log R) is in fact not a worst case time but an average case for uniformly distributed points and sufficiently small R.

The N^2 was for finding the set of points within radius R of each point. (For each of the N points, the distance to the remaining N-1 points must be checked).

The R^2 was assuming a uniform distribution of points, so that the number of points in each convex hull will be proportional to R^2. Calculating convex hull of R^2 points is O(R^2 log R).

Finally, taking the union of the N convex hulls I wasn't sure about and left out.